# How to see status of a git submodule library?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-status

I have a library in a git project which is a submodule, I will call it service-lib.

The serivce-lib is not developed by myself or my company, and in fact I am encouraged not to edit it.

How can I check the git status of this module to:

1. Check to makes sure I haven't accidentally edited/created a file
   in it
2. See any updates from the developers (i.e. so I can adopt
   any bug fixes they may have added)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git submodule has the following command to view submodule statuts.

`git submodule status path/to/submodule`

Answer (score 1):

Use the status command just like you will do with any other git repo

[image]

---

## ***`git submodule status`***

> Show the status of the submodules.
>
> This will print the SHA-1 of the currently checked out commit for **each submodule**, along with the submodule path and the output of git describe for the SHA-1.
>
> Each SHA-1 will be prefixed with - if the submodule is not initialized, + if the currently checked out submodule commit does not match the SHA-1 found in the index of the containing repository and U if the submodule has merge conflicts.
>
> If `--recursive` is specified, this command will recurse into nested submodules, and show their status as well.
>
> If you are only interested in changes of the currently initialized submodules with respect to the commit recorded in the index or the HEAD, `git status` and `git diff` will provide that information too (and can also report changes to a submodule’s work tree).

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have only one submodule, seeing its status is even simpler:

```
git submodule
```

That is because, before Git 2.22 (Q2 0219), submodule's default behavior wasn't documented in both git-submodule.txt and in the usage text of git-submodule.

See [commit 68cabbf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68cabbfda36b2e515802e13753637a987c4cf9a9) (15 Feb 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c388c12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c388c12c927dc42b1b8eb2368d3519a846483081), 07 Mar 2019)</sup>

Now the [documentation includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/68cabbfda36b2e515802e13753637a987c4cf9a9/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L30-L33):

> With no arguments, shows the status of existing submodules.
>   Several subcommands are available to perform operations on the submodules.